# getting started fpga video processing?

Tags: fpga, dsp, signal-processing, synthesis

Hi i am a electrical engineering student first year since we study only microcontrollers and processors I have decided to learn more about fpga (I have a little experience with spartan 3e vhdl) . My goal is to be able to perperform video processing on a video stream and detect ,track multiples objects . I have 4 months periode . For the fpga I think basys3 board from digilent will do fine ( 1800 kb of ram 90 dsp. Vivado ) ?
The problem I don't know where to begin ? What I should study ? Ho im gonna feed the video to the fpga ? any help would be great thanks

Comment: Step 1: Get admitted into the graduate EE program.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. If you have specific problems about processing video with an FPGA, then we can definitely answer those, but it looks like we could write a book about this one.

Comment: why ? i cant find any good learning materials online ? beside i am in school so its hard to combine two programs

Comment: ok Greg d'Eon i know its a extremely broad question i just need some help getting started , best tool for processing in fpga ? matlab ?

Comment: A good place to start would be Google. I am positive that you can find an "Intro to FPGAs" somewhere.

Comment: Greg d'Eon i have a exprience in fpga i did some projects in spartan 3e in high school (Vga controle, usb keyboard,counters .....) . is the basys3   a good starting board  to learn processing compared to minispartan6+?  basys3 :::33,280 logic cells in 5200 slices (each slice contains four 6-input LUTs and 8 flip-flops)
1,800 Kbits of fast block RAM
Five clock management tiles, each with a phase-locked loop (PLL)
90 DSP slices
Internal clock speeds exceeding 450MHz
On-chip analog-to-digital converter (XADC)

Comment: Documentation for the Digilent Basys3 FPGA test board is here
https://reference.digilentinc.com/basys3:basys3

You need an A/D (Analog to Digital converter) to bring an analog video signal to the FPGA. The Basys3 has a 12-bit A/D but it is limited to 1 MSPS which is fairly slow for video.
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug480_7Series_XADC.pdf

An advantage of the Basys3 is that it can output video in VGA format direct to a PC monitor.

Comment: For a 4-month video learning project I suggest:

1. Decide on a task such as "Generate an arrow-shaped cursor that can be superimposed on a video and moved around by commands from a) pushbuttons or b) mouse."
2. Simulate the various various horizontal and vertical counters in high-level language on a PC to get the result you want on a static image.
3. Check that the amounts of logic and memory you use are within the resources on the Basys3.
4. Use the FPGA design tools to configure the FPGA with your design.

See Reference Manual
http://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/BASYS3/Basys3_rm.pdf

Comment: I don't think you will have time to do more than read about other video processing tasks but here is a place to start:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_processing

Tracking moving objects in video is likely to demand fast manipulation of matrix variables, which may be too ambitious for a first project.

Comment: The board you suggest doesn't have a video input, take a board that has video input, video output and a good reference loopback design. You should be able to plug yourself somewhere  in the reference design to do your processing and see the result. Like the others, I believe 4 months is not a enough to do tracking or anything sophisticated, unless you find an IP core that does 90% of the work for you.

Comment: thanks guys for all the replays now i think i need to study more about Matlab . My primary goal is to learn about image and video processing . so im gonna stop dreaming and start with some easy things hopefully by the end of the summer i will be able to work something out

Answer (score 3):

FPGA is a logic device - thus you have to feed-in your video as a digital signal. So, let's assume that your image sensor (video source) provides you with depth resolution of 12bit (per pixel), 640x480 pixels image, and 30 frames per second, so your pixel rate feed in 640x480x30 pixels per second.

Life stream is a pixel by pixel process (that's how it is read out inside the image sensor register as an analog signal). Then it is converted by an ADC internally or externally ending up with a parallel or serial digital output. In parallel, you read all 12 bits of a pixel at once (at a pixel rate). In serial, you can read 1bit at a time, but 12 times the pixel rate. There are some sensors that have a mixed serial/parallel output, say 4 parallel outputs that provide serial 3 bit data at the pixel rate. In any case, you want to deserialize your signal, which is usually implemented on the FPGA.

Let's assume that you have a parallel video input (using 12bit bus?) and you feed in pixel by pixel. Obviously, to perform some processing, you need to collect the necessary amount of pixels, the whole frame, or several frames depending on the kind of processing operation. This is where the line buffers (image line), memories come in. After collecting the number of pixels you perform the filtering/processing - this is a completely different question that relates algorithm implementation techniques.

Without great experience of FPGA video processing, it is difficult to predict what size of the device will be sufficient enough. That's why, you design the logic and then perform estimation of required resources (using vivado), and then you will see which FPGA devises have enough resources. All this depends on the complexity of the video processing, video bitrate, speed, parallelism, and some other factors that I do not know about.

I would say that for a beginner writing a video processing VHDL implementation by hand is plain suicide. I have not written anything myself yet - I am a starter just like you. The way I am planning to approach it is first performing video processing in C (matlab), then translating the code to Simulink (as a block diagram) and then trying to convert it to Systems Generator (an Xilinx add-on for Simulink). This is not the only option, but for a beginner is right on.

Not to discourage, but 4 month for this project with zero experience will be intense, you will need some great support.

EDIT:

**The choice of the board** will depend on the interfacing requirements. Usually, the board is designed to fully exploit the resources of the FPGA device that is on it. See if it has enough accessible inputs/outputs for your application, master clock options, presence of SRAM/DRAM (for example, for video buffering), ability to perform real time simulation.

**The choice of the FPGA** depends on many factors specific to your application - read the last sentence of paragraph 4. After you have a description of you data and a better definition of your video processes, an experienced engineer might give you an opinion (guess) whether a given board (FPGA) should have enough resources to do the job.

I would suggest to start with creating a VHDL implementation and then, based on estimated resources, you could choose the board that will meet the requirements. I do not think that getting the board before will be of any help.

Comment: thanks for the replay first i need to learn how to do  video processing in matlab ,  we cant use Ip cores for fpga ?

Comment: I do not know about IP cores. If any available, why not use them? You definitely should start with some tutorials (not many of them) just to have a basic idea how things work (as opposed to microcontrolles and conventional line-by-line program execution). Choose the approach depending on whether this project is to "make it happen" or to "educate yourself".

Comment: thanks its just for educational purposes  last thing : what do you think about the basys 3 board gonna be fine? or minispartan6 is better